# Can one use Terraform templates with SageMaker ML Pipelines?

Tags: machine-learning, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codepipeline

SageMaker has ML Pipelines that come with “ML templates”, which I assume are Cloud Formation templates for machine learning pipelines.

Can one use custom Terraform templates instead of Cloud Formation? Where does one place the Terraform templates? Can this be done through the SageMaker UI?

Answer (score 2):

The ML Templates available in SageMaker are part of SageMaker Projects which are ServiceCatalog products (CloudFormation templates).

If you want to use Terraform to spin up your ML resources on SageMaker, you can do so but won't be able to leverage SageMaker Projects in the SageMaker Studio UI to launch the Terraform scripts.

--
I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.

Comment: Would you be able to use the templates in terraform, or be able to use custom templates? i.e. if I want to create a model deployment job, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use Terraform to provision the needed resources. For example this [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_domain) is for providing a SageMaker Domain resource. This is also a useful [step by step guide on using Terraform with SageMaker](https://towardsdatascience.com/terraform-sagemaker-part-1-terraform-initialization-a6470611ea92).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Terraform to deploy AWS CodePipeline or Jenkins or Gitlab CICD to orchestrate SageMaker workflow.